# How to edit events date in iOS calendar app with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, date, events, calendar

I search how to edit the date of my event in iOS calendar app. I have succeeded to add the event but the date is always the date of the day. I search how to programmatically a precise date (for example: May 10 2019 at 08:00 pm).

Here is the code I added to add the event in calendar.

```
import UIKit
import EventKit

class CalendarViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // To add event to iOS Calendar app
    @IBAction func addToCalendar(_ sender: Any) {

        let eventStore:EKEventStore = EKEventStore()

        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event) { (granted, error) in

            if (granted) && (error == nil)

            {
                print("granted \(granted)")
                print("error \(error)")

               let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
                event.title = "Concours de coinchée"
                event.startDate = Date()
                event.endDate = Date()
                event.notes = "Cantine scolaire de Goupillières"
                event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents

                do {
                     try eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
                } catch let error as NSError {

                    print("error : \(error)")
                }

                print("Save Event")

            } else {

                print("error : \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for changing the date:

```swift
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.year = 2020
    dateComponents.month = 1
    dateComponents.day = 1
    dateComponents.hour = 10
    dateComponents.minute = 30

    let startDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)

    dateComponents.hour = 11

    let endDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)

    let event: EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
    event.title = "Concours de coinchée"
    event.startDate = startDate
    event.endDate = endDate
    event.notes = "Cantine scolaire de Goupillières"
    event.calendar = eventStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents
```

Comment: Great! It works! Thanks a lot for your help!

You forgot the "event.endDate = eventDate" line which caused an error and who could not add the event, but without consequence. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, I'm glad I could help! Would you accept the answer so other people can see it works at a glance?

Comment: Yes, it's done! Do you know how to add an end hour for the event please? If you know of course... :p

Comment: Sorry it took a while, you just do exactly what you did for the `startDate` but with a different time and then add it to the event as the `endDate`

Comment: I've updated my answer so it includes how to change the end date.

Comment: Ok tanks you! Just to specify the duration of the event?